# Как отменить проверку поля textarea в комментариях?

Tags: php, wordpress

В форму для комментариев добавлено ещё одно новое поле, и теперь нужно сделать, чтобы поле `textarea` не было обязательным.
Как отменить проверку данного поля `textarea` ?
Сейчас выдаёт такое сообщение:  `ОШИБКА: пожалуйста, введите комментарий.`
файл **wp-includes/comment.php**

```
if ( '' == $comment_content ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'require_valid_comment', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: please type a comment.' ), 200 );
}
```

ведь данную строчку нельзя менять. Как это сделать другим путём?

Comment: А почему менять нельзя?

Comment: @Юрий, потому-что после обновления вордпресс данная правка пропадёт

Comment: Там хуков нет совсем, я посмотрел. Попробуйте совет в конце статьи https://misha.blog/wordpress/block-autospam-comments.html